# custom border frame for Gallery widget

Tags: android, selection, border, gallery

Is there a way to define/customize a border around the currently selected `Gallery` item? I know, i can create a `Drawable` and draw four lines into that but there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I did the following:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/group_info"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@drawable/list">
```

@drawable/list is a 9patch.
Inside the `LinearLayout` I added a `View` with the proper margin.